# No camera topics

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have been trying to set up a physical turtlebot3 following this: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/.
I've done all the setup, and doen up until 4.SLAM. I noticed that they have a camera there even though it's not being used in SLAM. When I try running the turtlebot3 bringup launch I get no camera topic. When I try launching the turtlebot3_rpicamera node I get errors. Using TB3 Waffle Pi with a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and RPi camera.

The error is:
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [raspicam_node/raspicam_node]: cannot locate node of type [raspicam_node] in package [raspicam_node]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to excecutable (chmod +x)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391646/no-camera-topics/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-25**:
Hi @Roshan can you pls post the errors

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-11-25**:
Edited in error

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-11-25**:
@Roshan A similar question #q391526 was asked less than 48 hours ago. You might want to follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS and Ubuntu and recently I was also struggling to make the camera work for turtlebot3 waffle_pi.
For me, I followed this route and now the camera is working fine in SLAM, the topics are available and rqt_image_view also shows the live feed from the camera.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS-noetic with a Turtlebot3 waffle_pi robot hosting a Raspberry Pi 4 2GB SBC.

The issue here is that the raspicam_node for noetic is difficult to set up as most methods require deleting the previous catkin_ws and building a new one. However, I followed the last method in this [link text](http://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node/issues/112). I will sum it up for you:

First of all, make sure the camera is working using the raspistill command and the peripherals for the camera are enabled in raspi-config.

Test it as:

```
raspistill -v -o test.jpg
```

Clone the package from github in your catkin_ws/src folder:

```
 cd catkin_ws/src

git clone https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node
```

Install the libraries:

```
sudo apt install libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi0 libpigpiod-if-dev
```

Install some packages:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-compressed-image-transport ros-noetic-camera-info-manager ros-noetic-diagnostic-updater
```

Afterward, compile the catkin_ws and source:

```
cd ..

catkin_make

source devel/setup.bash
```

The next thing is running two launch files at the same time to visualize the camera input in SLAM.

First, run a roscore on the remote-PC:

```
roscore
```

Open a secure shell with a robot and launch raspicam_node:

```
roslaunch raspicam_node camerav2_1280x960.launch
```

Open another secure shell and bring up the robot:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
```

Now in the remote PC:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_slam.launch
```

In the new terminal window:

```
rqt_image_view
```

The image from the camera would be visible in both Rviz (where SLAM is running) and the rqt_image_view window.
Also, if you do 'rostopic list' in remote-PC, you would be able to see the camera-related topic published by raspicam_node.

This method worked for me. I apologize for any typos or inconvenience.

Thank you,

Muhammad Umar Farooq

---

Originally posted by [Muhammad Umar](https://answers.ros.org/users/91122/muhammad-umar/) with karma: 36 on 2021-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-08**:
Hi Muhammad nice complete answer. If you could format using 10101 for the code portions it will help with readability